What is the quickest way to collect blue studs in Lego Battles
I play the Nintendo DS Lego Battles. I'm trying to collect all mini-figures, concept arts, and maps. They all cost blue studs, which are collected in story mode (20 placed in each mission). What is the fastest way to collect tons of blue studs?
(Also, does anyone play Lego Battles anymore?)
